# Sails update query, output should have selected colums

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I am using sails-waterline ORM for my application.

I know how to get the selected columns in find query using 'select', but is it possible to get the same with the update query?

If yes, let me know, how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is impossible with `update()`

http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/update